How to fix an inconsistent null reference using Array Godot 4.3 C#
I'm having a strange and inconsistent null reference exception with an array.
The problem:
When the main generator calls for the tiles to find their neighbours, I get a null reference exception in the line neighbourArray[0] = world.GetNodeOrNull(nameNW);
The strange thing:
It only happens to first-column nodes
Theres no problem if EVERY tile is given a Forest or Desert biome in GiveBiomeType, but giving None biome type to leftovers only stops the error happening in the first few iterations.
What I'm doing:
I'm experimenting with a basic object-oriented world generator. The main generator creates a grid of 'tiles', instantiates them, gives a given number of them a biome (enum) and calls a function in them to find their neighbours and 'spread' their biome type.
I thought the problem was with get_node_or_null, and tried has_node but the for loop at the bottom of the find neighbours function proves this wasn't it.
I suspected the Array was being randomly wiped, but using a list doesn't change anything.
Here is the main chunk of the main generator:
IEnumerator<double> GenerateNew()
{
    // foreach (Node2D t in tilesArray)
    // {
    //     if(t != null){t.QueueFree();}
    // }

    yield return Timing.WaitForSeconds(0.5);

    GD.Print("-Gen: Starting gen");
    yield return Timing.WaitUntilDone(Timing.RunCoroutine(InitialiseGrid().CancelWith(this)));
    GD.Print("Gen: Tiles placed, giving biome types");
    yield return Timing.WaitUntilDone(Timing.RunCoroutine(GiveBiomeTypes().CancelWith(this)));
    GD.Print("Gen: Biomes given, call find neighbours ");
    yield return Timing.WaitUntilDone(Timing.RunCoroutine(CallFindNeighbours().CancelWith(this)));
    GD.Print("Neighburs should be found, start spread");
    yield return Timing.WaitUntilDone(Timing.RunCoroutine(CallBiomeSpread().CancelWith(this)));
    GD.Print("Gen: ");


    // TEMP
    yield return Timing.WaitForSeconds(0.2f);

    GD.Print("Gen: Generating finished");
    //    DEBUGPrintTileArray();

}

IEnumerator<double> InitialiseGrid()
{

    int arrayIndex = -1;

    for (int x = 0; x < numOfTiles; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < numOfTiles; y++)
        {
            arrayIndex++;

            var newTile = tile.Instantiate();
            AddChild(newTile);

            var t = newTile as Node2D;
            t.Position = new Vector2(x * sizeOfTiles, y * sizeOfTiles);

            //Naming
            string one = x.ToString();
            string two = y.ToString();
            t.Name = one + "-" + two;

            tilesArray[arrayIndex] = t;
        }
    }

    yield return Timing.WaitForSeconds(0.001f); // Appease coroutine
}


IEnumerator<double> GiveBiomeTypes()
{
    if (numOfForest > 0)
    {
        for (int f = 0; f < numOfForest; f++)
        {
            int rf = GD.RandRange(0, tilesArray.Length - 1);
            var sf = tilesArray[rf] as TestTile;

            if (sf.biomeType == BiomeType.None)
            {
                sf.biomeType = BiomeType.Forest;
                sf.world = this;

                // temp
                //    GD.Print("Gen: Biome given to " + sf.Name);
                //    sf.FindNeighbours();
            }
            else
            {
                f--;
            }
        }
    }
    else { GD.Print("Gen: Number of forest is 0"); }


    if (numOfDesert > 0)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d < numOfDesert; d++)
        {
            int rd = GD.RandRange(0, tilesArray.Length - 1);
            var sd = tilesArray[rd] as TestTile;

            if (sd.biomeType == BiomeType.None)
            {
                sd.biomeType = BiomeType.Forest;
                sd.world = this;

                // temp
                //    GD.Print("Gen: Biome given to " + sd.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                d--;
            }
        }
    }
    else { GD.Print("Gen: Number of deserts is 0"); }


    int leftOvers = (numOfTiles * numOfTiles) - (numOfForest + numOfDesert);

    if (leftOvers > 0)
    {
        for (int lo = 0; lo < leftOvers; lo++)
        {
            int rlo = GD.RandRange(0, tilesArray.Length - 1);
            var slo = tilesArray[rlo] as TestTile;

            if (slo.biomeType == BiomeType.None)
            {
                slo.biomeType = BiomeType.None;
                slo.world = this;

                // temp
                //    GD.Print("Gen: Biome given to " + sd.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                lo--;
            }
        }
    }
    yield return Timing.WaitForSeconds(0.001f); // Appease coroutine
}

IEnumerator<double> CallFindNeighbours()
{
    foreach (Node2D t in tilesArray)
    {
        GD.Print("\n Tiles array tile : " + t.Name);

        var ts = t as TestTile;
        ts.FindNeighbours();
    }
    yield return Timing.WaitForSeconds(0.001f); // Appease coroutine
}

And here is the problem function being called on our instantiated tiles:

public void FindNeighbours()
{
    GD.Print("Tile " + Name + " with type " + biomeType + " finding neighbours: ");
    string name = Name;
    int x = name[0] - '0';
    int y = name[2] - '0';



    //    GD.Print("\n Name broken up is : " + x + " and " + y + "\n");

    int w = x - 1;
    int e = x + 1;
    int n = y - 1;
    int s = y + 1;

    string nameNW = w + "-" + n;
    string nameN = x + "-" + n;
    string nameNE = e + "-" + n;
    neighbourArray[0] = world.GetNodeOrNull<Node2D>(nameNW); //Should not matter if its null
    neighbourArray[1] = world.GetNodeOrNull<Node2D>(nameN);
    neighbourArray[2] = world.GetNodeOrNull<Node2D>(nameNE);

    string nameW = w + "-" + y;
    string nameE = e + "-" + y;
    neighbourArray[3] = world.GetNodeOrNull<Node2D>(nameW);
    neighbourArray[4] = world.GetNodeOrNull<Node2D>(nameE);

    string nameSW = w + "-" + s;
    string nameS = x + "-" + s;
    string nameSE = e + "-" + s;
    neighbourArray[5] = world.GetNodeOrNull<Node2D>(nameSW);
    neighbourArray[6] = world.GetNodeOrNull<Node2D>(nameS);
    neighbourArray[7] = world.GetNodeOrNull<Node2D>(nameSE);


    // When sum of numOfForst + numOfDesert == total tiles, everything works fine. This loop shows that
    for (int i = 0; i < neighbourArray.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (neighbourArray[i] != null)
        {
            GD.Print(neighbourArray[i].Name);
        }
        else
        {
            GD.Print("Found null node");
        }
    }

}

I'm at a loss. Any ideas welcomed.
